# If A and B be two subsets of a set X, then prove that A ⊆ B iff X-B ⊆ X-A.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If A and B be two subsets of a set X, then prove that A ⊆ B iff X-B ⊆ X-A.

**My attempt**
Let A ⊆ B then x $\in$ X-B implies $x \in X$ but $x \notin B$ since A ⊆ B $x \notin A$ therefore $x \in X$ but $x \notin A$ i. e., $x \in X-A$ therefore X-B ⊆ X-A.

I don't know how to prove converse part please help me

Comment: Change $A$ to $X-A$ and $B$ to $X-B$ in the direct part.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a proof that $A \subseteq B \implies X-B \subseteq X-A$ then $¬(X-B \subseteq X-A) \implies ¬(A \subseteq B)$ which is equivalent to $(X-B \supset X-A) \implies (A \supset B)$ so $(X-A \subset X-B) \implies (B \subset A)$. Then just show that if $X-A=X-B$ then the statement holds.